# TV provider Delete does not work with where clause

Tags: java, android, sqlite, jobservice

I am trying to delete some channels inserted by my app in TV.db via a JobService asynctaks.

Each time i am getting security exception while deleting.

```
Process: com.app, PID: 7026
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Selection not allowed for content://android.media.tv/channel?input=<My package>%2F.live.TvInputService&browsable_only=false
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1574)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:185)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.delete(ContentProviderNative.java:544)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:1299)
        at com.TvContractUtills.updateChannelsWithGraceNote(TvContractUtills.java:173)
        at com.EpgUpdateTask.doInBackground(EpgUpdateTask.java:48)
        at com.EpgUpdateTask.doInBackground(EpgUpdateTask.java:11)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

This line of code causing above error

```
resolver.delete(channelsUri,TvContract.Channels._ID+ " in ("+getListOfIds(availableChannelMap) +" )" , null);
```

availableChannelMap returns comma separated list of channel ids.

Same code works when i kept the where clause to null.

```
  resolver.delete(channelsUri,null , null);
```

Any idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a channel, you need to call the `ContentResolver` like this

```kotlin
context.contentResolver.delete(TvContractCompat.buildChannelUri(channelId), null, null)
```

If you want to delete multiple channels, put it in a loop. I am not sure if it's the correct way. I don't see any bulk delete method available in the `providers` API. It works though.

Comment: Yeah, then it look likes functions second and third argument is useless, except to the case where we want to delete single row based on condition.

Comment: Yeah. The API needs more documentation